# Best Wordpress Gallery Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to place a photo gallery on my wordpress blog. I use NextGEN Gallery but I don't like the lightbox (The rest is awesome). Can I change only the lightbox? Do you know any better plugin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TickBox that is selectable under the Gallery Options of NextGen or installing one of this plugins for nextgen:

1. [SmoothGallery NextGen Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-smooth-gallery/)
2. [NextGen Gallery Effects](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/effects-for-nextgen-gallery/)
3. [JJ Slider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jj-nextgen-jquery-slider/)

Hope this it help!

Comment: I never saw TickBox option! This looks great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just one more gallery plugin [Gallereo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gallereo/). It allows you to create a Google+ like layout with fancy preview.

Check some screenshots:

*After gallery is loaded the plugin creates Google+ like images layout.*
[image: After gallery is loaded the plugin creates Google+ like images layout.]

*After clicking on an image the preview popup will appear.*
[image: After clicking on an image the preview popup will appear.]

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is Envira but I have listed 9 best plugins for galleries [here](https://digitalwatchers.com/wordpress/wordpress-plugins/best-wordpress-gallery-plugins-photos-images/)
Hope it helps